# Enable mixed content loading in latest Chrome and firefox with http headers

Tags: apache, google-chrome, http, firefox, browser

I have a website that has to be served under HTTPS

However, there is a section of the site that displays BBC news stories within an iframe which is in a popup window. Here the content is not shown as both browsers say the BBC content is insecure (i.e.mixed content).

I have tried setting the header `Content-Security-Policy`:
to

`"default-src 'self' *.my_domian.net http://*.my_domian.net http://*.bbc.co.uk *.fonts.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"`

Which has an effect on other content so it is working. I have also checked the headers are sent.

However, both Chrome and Firefox continue to tell me the BBC content is insecure and it isn't shown in the iframe.

Is it possible to allow content from bbc.co.uk on a secure site ?
Have I miss understood the purpose of Content-Security-Policy ?

I have also tried `frame-src` in the header with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148944/mixed-content-in-chrome-and-ie/27444591#27444591

Answer (score 0):

CSP level 2 is already being applied in Chrome, and level 2 has additional frame handling.

see here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-frame-ancestors
and here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-frame-src

frame-src is being deprecated, user frame-ancestors