# Mixed content in Chrome and IE

Tags: google-chrome, security, iframe, https, mixed-content

In my HTTPS enabled site I have added an iframe that should show content from my other site, but it is not working under https.

```html
<iframe  src="//myothersite.com"></iframe>
```

In Firefox latest version everything works good.

In Chrome, the iframe isn't loaded and in the console I see these two errors

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mysite' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://myothersite.com'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

In IE content load incorrectly and I see an alert message; if I click Allow Insecure Content, it loads correctly.

The question is: how I can do that IE and Chrome as in Firefox (load mixed content without any alerts)?

Note: I haven't changed any browser settings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually Firefox has started to do the same: [How to fix a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

It makes sense. If the user access a site using HTTPS is expecting to have a secured experience, and he may not be aware of parts of the application loading under not secure connections. That is the reason why the browser blocks such inconsistency.

You will need to provide HTTPS on myothersite.com.

Comment: Ok,It make sence if myothersite.com is not my site.But myothersite.com is my site and I can quarantee secure.I thinck browsers should provide such functionality

Comment: You cannot guarantee anything. If the connection is not secure, anybody in the middle can eavesdrop the connection. IFRAMEs are like another browser tab, they use their own connection, and in this case it is insecure.

Comment: i agree,but why firefox allow using insecure without any alerts?

Comment: Firefox's mistake. In the link I provided it says it is blocking mixed content from v23.

Answer (score 10):

Obviously it's best not to have mixed content to prevent MITM attacks but for those who can't control the url this should do the trick:

Change the **src="http://linkToUrl.com"** to

> **src="//linkToUrl.com/script.js"**

Comment: That wont solve the problem that sub http request send by the `script.js`.  Add this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`.

Comment: A combination of using src="//linkToUrl.com/script.js" and adding the suggested meta tag @towry has here solved the issue for me. I believe this is the best answer here.

Comment: where do i have to configure this thing?

Comment: save my day @JisuKim82

Comment: At least in Chrome, this only results in an https request being made. It will work if the source is able to serve the content via https, but then you might as well just specify https

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfbdo.png)

when i set the url : 
`<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/download/1.txt"></a>` from a https request, it report error : 
Mixed Content: The page at `'https://127.0.0.1/index.html'` was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource `'http://127.0.0.1:8080/download/1.txt'`.

```
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

when i added the `target="_blank"` to the url: `<a target="_blank" href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/download/1.txt">`, it works!  , it works! 
it's well known that `target="_blank"` means opening the linked document in a new window or tab or a new request!

Comment: this is in the iframe!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry this isn't as technical as the other answers, but I had the same problem linking jsquery like this, and for me it fixed just by changing `http://` to `https://`. It may not work, but it worked for me and it might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having other complication with CloudFlare, it doesn't load as the file has been cached as http. Just go to CloudFlare and "Purge Everything" in cache tab, or else turn on "Development Mode".