# Xcode swift error App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP

Tags: xcode, swift, http, https

I have added the required values into my `.plist` file as shown in the screenshot below

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

but I still get this error:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

What else could be causing this issue?

[image]

All of the errors below are displayed

> { URL: http://example.com }
>   2015-10-21 00:20:30.694 SwiftSignatureSystem[1226:36450] App Transport
>   Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it
>   is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's
>   Info.plist file. fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an
>   error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could
>   not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the
>   use of a secure connection."
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd33c8951e0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "The resource could not be
>   loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a
>   secure connection."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://example.com,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
>   App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection., NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://example.com}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://example.com,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://example.com, NSLocalizedDescription=The
>   resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy
>   requires the use of a secure connection.}: file
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.0.59/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 50

Comment: have you cleaned and re-built your project since this change? tried restarting xcode?

Comment: thank you i tried restarting xcode but same error is appered...

Is there any other way？？
I added photos. info.plist but I like there are two, or this would be the cause?

Comment: Your 2nd screenshot shows a nested duplicated "Supporting files" folder. Delete the inner duplicate.

Comment: Thank you. i delete inner duplicate .  but same error is appered...

Please look so was up a photo of info.plist

Comment: It was successful. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems a mixed content issue.

[Mixed content in Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148944/mixed-content-in-chrome-and-ie/27444591)

If your user agent loads the page under HTTPS, it should refuse to load unsecure items.

Comment: It was successful. Thank you!!