# Firebase console realtime database not showing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The console window for Firebase Database just keeps spinning, waiting for results. This is a brand new setup; why should it not load?

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1
>   WebSocket connection to 'wss://firebase.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1
>   WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1
>   WebSocket connection to 'wss://firebase.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1
>   WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1

[See Captured Request using fiddler](http://oi63.tinypic.com/35jzgwm.jpg)

Comment: On what platform are you opening the console? What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using window 8 and google chrome browser Version 52.0.2743.116. i'm having android app project

Comment: see this one
http://oi63.tinypic.com/35jzgwm.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Please include the screenshot in your question (there's an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39494121/edit link for that purpose) and use Stack Overflow's preferred image hosting service.

Comment: Try without Fiddler please, as I have no idea whether it interferes with the web socket upgrades. In addition, can you try [this test page](https://www.firebase.com/test.html)? It will try a few ways of connecting to the Firebase servers. Finally: if your problem is when accessing the Firebase Database console in Chrome on Windows, does Android have anything to do with it? If not, I'd rather ignore that and focus on the problematic platform.

Comment: i tried test link. in last i got this thing - 
20.00: Diagnostic failed after 20 second timeout hit. Please send logs to firebase-support@google.com... should i send you entire logs on email id ?

Comment: In Addition - I thought it might be Google Chrome Problem so that i have also updated it with latest version Version 53.0.2785.113 m. but problem still persist

Comment: It is more likely that this is a problem on your local network, such as a firewall interfering with the connection. The test page should give a pretty clear description of what it is trying, definitely more than just saying where it failed.

Comment: how can it be network issue ? Other things like storage etc. are working well without any interruption.

Comment: See this log -

The page at 'https://console.firebase.google.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://nav.brotstation.com/?time=1472791936'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

see this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148944/mixed-content-in-chrome-and-ie

Comment: I quickly checked and can't find anything on our side that would load from nav.brotstation.com.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too, i cannot access firebase realtime db from both console and app yesterday. But it is weird that if i connect to vpn using betternet chrome extension, it works ok. I just tested with this link [firebase.com/test.html](https://www.firebase.com/test.html). In case no vpn connection it shows "Diagnostic failed after 20 second timeout hit....". With vpn connection it is ok with log "1.31: Testing REST GET via jsonp ... 3.32: REST GET succeeded ... 13.73: Everything looks good." This problem happens frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got answers. There were running some unauthorized services along with google chrome. This software did work for me **SpyHunter**
(Note: I'm not promoting any software here but this did job and i must appreciate.)