# Laravel ssl lock is not showing

Tags: laravel, ssl

I have added ssl to my website https://phone-pedia.com.
lock is only appearing on homepage. On other pages, lock does not appear. I tried to clear cache but issue is still here.

Is it a Laravel issue or ssl problem ?

If mixed content is the problem then why homepage has a lock. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixed content in Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148944/mixed-content-in-chrome-and-ie)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome says your site uses sources (such as images) from non-secured origins. You should use in your views the `asset_secure` helper instead of `asset`. If you already do, check if you use in other sources from non-secured origins. Otherwise it has to do with your SSL.

Comment: after adding asset_secure helper images are gone.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed content on some of your pages. If you look at your browser console you'll see a message like the following:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/path' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://example.com/storage/products/images/example.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

You need to serve all of your content over HTTPS.